# What do Hawking/Ellis mean exactly by "non-rotating families of geodesics"?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, rotation, geodesics, vortex

In *The Large Scale Structure of Space-Time*, Hawking and Ellis refer twice (page 4, page 78) to *non-rotating families of geodesics*.

I don't know what that means. Is a *rotating geodesic* one that represents an object revolving around another object? Is it as simple as that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do Hawking/Ellis mean exactly by "non-rotating families of geodesics"?

They mean *geodesic congruences with vanishing vorticity tensor*. The definition of vorticity tensor could be found in Hawking&Ellis on page 82, or in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)#The_kinematical_decomposition_of_a_timelike_congruence).

> Is a *rotating geodesic* one that represents an object revolving around another object?

It is not *a geodesic* that rotates but *a family* of geodesics, and vorticity tensor represents the rate of rotation for neighboring curves.

Comment: And page 69 of Hawking/Ellis has a definition of congruences....  Page 216 of Wald's book General Relativity has a good description of congruences as well.